# Reentrant Lock - possible outputs?

Tags: java

given lock situation:

[image]

I think I got this right but I need to be sure so I'm asking you guys if I made a mistake.

I got two possible outputs for variables "x" and "y" in this programm:

```
1. Lines 1.1 - 1.7: y = 5,
   Lines 2.1 - 2.3: x = 15.

2. Lines 2.1 - 2.3: x = 11,
   rest             y = 25.
```

are there any other outputs in this exact situation?

Comment: Remove the link and provide the code in plain text.

Comment: You mean output when both threads are finished?

Comment: yes output when both are finished, and sorry i forgot to add: both variables are atomic!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lock block on the right had side can occur in one of three places:

- Before 1.1
- Between 1.3 and 1.5
- After 1.7

The values of `x` and `y` for these three cases are

- `x = 11, y = 25`
- `x = 11, y = 5`
- `x = 15, y = 5`